# Not all duplicates are removed

Tags: python, nlp, preprocessor

I have a list of sentences (+200,000), in which certain sentences are repeated a couple of times. However, I want only a list of unique sentences. I have tried two different codes, and while some of the duplicates have been removed, I still notice that some duplicates have remained in the dataset. Any idea why my codes haven't worked entirely and what I can do to change this? Thanks in advance!

The codes I've tried are the following;
`unique = list(set(all_data))`
and

```
for line in all_data:
 if line not in unique:
  unique.append(line)
```

Comment: `set(all_data)` should absolutely work. Are you sure they are exact duplicates? Maybe the sentences different by a space character, upper/lower case letter or punctuation mark. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll check for that!

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
mylist = ['Hey','Hey','Heyy']
newlist = list(np.unique(mylist)) #np.unique's output is an array
```

Now `newlist` would be

```py
['Hey','Heyy']
```